# Multiple Switch statements with multiple cases?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a switch statement that would have a similar effect to what I show in the code below, but (obviously), it's not working. It will be impossible to have something selected in both combo boxes at once. Any thoughts on how to accomplish this? I'm updating an older program, and I'm trying not to re-write a large chunk of the code.

```
    switch ((cboMAIN.SelectedIndex) || (cboMAINalternate.SelectedIndex))
            {
                case 0:
                    OutputString1 = "A";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    OutputString1 = "C";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    OutputString1 = "E";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    OutputString1 = "F";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    OutputString1 = "I";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    OutputString1 = "J";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    OutputString1 = "K";
                    break;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
switch ((cboMAIN.SelectedIndex > -1) ? cboMAIN.SelectedIndex : cboMAINalternate.SelectedIndex) 
{
```

Comment: That worked. I'm new to programming; I've never used an inline IF statement before. Cool solution!

Comment: @DanCallahan Per your logic where one will *always* be valid, it made sense to use an inline conditional to check for the main one; if its value was unchaged, use the alternate. :-)

Comment: I believe 0 is a valid index; I think it should be `cboMAIN.SelectedIndex > -1` instead. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex.aspx)

Comment: I did end up having to change it to -1. Other than that, it worked just fine, though.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible (at least not the way you're doing it).

The question would be, what are you trying to achieve? If you'd have some kind of toggle to switch between both indexes, you could do something like that:

```
bool useAlternative = ...;
switch(useAlternative ? cboMAINalternate.SelectedIndex : cboMAIN.Selectedindex) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is always a selected item in a select element, so you have to check for the one that you consider to be no selecton, for example the first item:

```
var item = cboMAIN.SelectedIndex;
if (item = 0) item = cboMAINalternate.SelectedIndex;

switch (item) {
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the concisest way:

```
switch (Math.Max(cboMAIN.SelectedIndex, cboMAINalternate.SelectedIndex))
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedindex.aspx), `SelectedIndex` will return `-1` if the selection is empty on a `ComboBox`.

The following code should choose a `ComboBox` with a selection and go through your switch statement, or fail if neither has a selection:

```
ComboBox comboBoxToUse;

if (cboMAIN.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
    comboBoxToUse = cboMAIN;
}
else if (cboMAINalternate.SelectedIndex > -1)
{
    comboBoxToUse = cboMAINalternate;
}
else
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Neither combo box contains a selection.");
}

switch (comboBoxToUse.SelectedIndex)
{
    ...
}
```

You may also want to throw an exception if both `ComboBox`es have a selection.